# Salesforce Case Feed custom button problem

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

We are just switching on the case feed within our Salesforce org but have noticed a rather irritating
issue. We have a number of custom buttons and when we go into the list and click on the link /
button within the drop down list all works well.

### [image]

for example 'Case ID' is simply a javascript alert that shows the Case ID (this is just an example). We click from the list as in one of the values as shown here

[image]

and we get this:

[image]

if we do this from the default value in the list

[image]

then we get redirected to ( http://{instance}.salesforce.com/undefined )

[image]

this seems to be the case for any javascript buttons only. If the button is simply a link to some normal or visualforce page, it works fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a workaround until Salesforce fix what seems like an apparent platform issue? I'd love a solution that is efficient, i.e. not requires redirecting to some visual force page which does what the button should do and the redirects back to the case we came from.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. How are you creating this drop down list?

Comment: That's how custom buttons are rendered in the case feed, it's built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. Salesforce have confirmed that the behavior is a bug with no known release date for fix. The best workaround is to switch from custom button to custom links which are rendered differently in case feed (one by one in a list, not as options in a dropdown). That means all "buttons" are visible all the time and clicking them will work as you expect without bugs.

Comment: Good to know.  Can you include a link to the bug on the Salesforce known issues site, so that future users can check on the progress of a solution without pinging you?

Comment: I would have if they would have had the courtesy of putting it there. My company has recently evaluated case feed and found 5 issues that we've raised with SF. All of our cases have been closed as bugs, none have been listed as known issues or given a fix-date. None have perfect workarounds. Oh how I wish it were my decision to use some other system....

Comment: @MartinPeters it would be great if you could create a new post with the issues you have encountered, to share the knowledge with the community.