# Custom Buttons on Feed Views

Tags: custom-button, page-layout, feeditem, casefeed

Does anyone know why the custom buttons on the new Feed View Layouts released in Spring '14 all collapse into one button when viewed on the left panel or right panel?

It is such weird behaviour. Yes, sure, collapse the buttons into a drop down list, but why choose the first button to be the only visible button? The other buttons have no relationship to the first button.

[image: button showing two buttons collapsed into one]

There must be a reason, surely?

I have added a bit of a rant here https://tdd.instawiki.com/display/SF/Feed+Views#FeedViews-buttons

See also this post [Salesforce Case Feed custom button problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/salesforce-case-feed-custom-button-problem), describing a bug with the buttons in Case Feed, and a suggestion from Salesforce to use Custom links instead. This may get around this issue, but it means changing all your buttons then. And it's not good UI to click on a link to "do somthing" - a link should "go somewhere"

(also, if someone could add a tag for feed-views for me that would be great).

Comment: It also appears that the related list links are broken.  They all show a zero record count regardless of how many actual records are in the list.  The hover functionality also seems to be missing.